# Python - How to call an external function from a class then returning back to the class

Tags: python, class, selenium, automated-tests

OK to clarify I am attempting to do data driven test on a site using selenium:
The main class code is:

```
from  a_folder.abc_file import userJourney
from  a_folder.a1_file import contact

@ddt
class testScenario(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

    def test_main_page(arg1, arg2):
         if arg1 == 'yes':
             return userJourney(arg1, arg2)

         if arg 2 == 'no':
             return contact(arg1, arg2)


    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
```

The arguments are passed in from a csv file

userJourney() and contact() functions are imported from an external file

The issue Im having is that arg1 and arg2 can both be true at the same time so i would expect both functions(userJouney and contact) to be executed but the test is only executing one function then it goes straight to tearDownClass function. Any ideas on what I am missing?

abc_file.py is something like

```
def userJourney(arg1, arg2):
   # Find element and click
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one method will be executed because you are using 'return' in both cases. So, if arg1 == 'yes', userJourney function will be executed and after that test_main_page will exit and return control to caller because you used 'return' keyword before call to userJourney. Next case will not be executed because method is finished at this point.

You should probably remove 'return' keyword from both cases. I am not sure what are you trying to test here but that is another thing.

Comment: Thanks, if i remove 'return' keyword then how would i call function from another file?

Comment: Actually worked without the return key word just be calling the function name. Thank you

Comment: `return` just indicates that you want to you want to stop current function and return control to the calling function. It also gives result value to calling function, if you give some value after `return`.